# how can i do calculations with a fetched data and an input in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, math

i want to multiply the price with the input quantity as shown in the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYVH3.png)

here is my .html :
how can i make it to read each price in the array and multiply it by the input quantity?

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- adding Quantity and calculation stuff-->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="itemName1">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Item-Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.itemName1 | uppercase}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="price1">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{element.price1}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="discount1">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Discount </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.discount1 | percent}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="tax1">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tax </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.tax1 | percent}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity1">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Quantity </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
         <mat-form-field class="example-width" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Quantity</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="number" [formControl]="quNnumber">
      </mat-form-field></mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  <h2>your Gross Total is : {{result}}</h2>
```

and here is my .ts :

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {itemName1 : 'Asus' , quantity1 : '' , price1: 300 , discount1 : 0.07 , tax1 : 0.04 },
  {itemName1 : 'Apple' , quantity1 : '' , price1: 600 , discount1 : 0.03 , tax1 : 0.07 },
  {itemName1 : 'Samsung' , quantity1 : '' , price1: 500 , discount1 : 0.05 , tax1 : 0.01 },
];
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
  // table stuff
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['itemName1', 'price1', 'discount1','tax1','quantity1'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
  quNnumber = new FormControl('');
  pricenumber = new FormControl('');
  result!: number;
  Addnumber(){
    // this.result = parseInt(this.pricenumber) * parseInt(this.quNnumber);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably should see what [FormArrays](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) are in Angular. You can create them with the [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) and access data which user writes in every FormControl you create, like `quNumber` in your code, with `this.quNumber.value`.

This assuming that you have a 'Submit' button or something like this. If you want an automatic update of the price as soon as your user inserts a value, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081169/adding-updating-text-value-of-an-input-field-after-change-angular) to see how to update your view along with every input field change.